# What is the best way to create webdriver instance in selenium Python with Pytest

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, pytest

I am new to python, I want to create web driver instance
I found two ways

First : Create Fixture and use Fixture in that in the Base Class and Inherit that Base Class where ever required. But this is not working. Here Setup fixture is correct in conftest.py file

Base Class:

```
@pytest.mark.usefixtures("setup")
class BaseTest:

    @staticmethod
    def go_to_url(url):
        print(".............Launching Application URL : " + url)
        # Driver.Instance.get(url)
        Driver.Instance.get(url)

    @staticmethod
    def maximize_window_size():
        print("..............Maximizing browser window..............")
        Driver.Instance.maximize_window()
```

Page Object :

```
Class page_object_class1:
value_xpath="//div[@id='excr']"
SeleniumUIAction.IsDisplayed(self.value_xpath)
```

Action Class: **This give error like SeleniumUIAction does not have 'driver' property**. Here we are inheriting BaseTest Class so I think it should be auto come from BaseTest Class. Reason I am able to launch and maximize browser so till BaseTest Class I am getting reference of driver but when I refer that driver in page object class that is giving error. Any suggestion will be highly appreciated

```
class SeleniumUIAction(BaseTest):

    def click_element(self,value_xpath):
        self.driver.find_element_by_xpath(value_xpath).click()
```

Second: Create Driver.py without class as below and use it wherever required using Driver.Instance. I did not find issue with this second approach but dont know this will support parallel execution or not

```
from selenium import webdriver

Instance = None

def Initialize():
    global Instance
    Instance = webdriver.Chrome("C://hromedriver.exe")
    Instance.implicitly_wait(5)
    return Instance
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what I use and it works pretty much fine for me.

```
@pytest.fixture()
    def test_setup(self):
        #initiating chrome driver
        global driver
        chrome_options=Options()
        chrome_options.add_argument('--start-maximized')
        driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r"{{Your driver path}}",
                                  chrome_options=chrome_options)

    def test_01(self, test_setup):
            driver.get(//page_url//)
            actual_title=driver.title
```

Comment: I am using driver in Page Object with extended BaseClass. In same class, that is working fine for me as well